# Python saying I'm passing in too many parameters to my function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some python code that contains unit tests like below:

```
class SunCalcTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `suncalc.py`."""
    def near(val1, val2):
        return abs(val1 - val2) < (margin or 1E-15)

    def test_getPositions(self):
        """Get sun positions correctly"""
        sunPos = suncalc.getPosition(self.date, self.lat, self.lng)
        az = sunPos["azimuth"]
        res = self.near(az, -2.5003175907168385)
```

But when I run this I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 64, in test_getPositions
    res = self.near(az, -2.5003175907168385)
TypeError: near() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am new to python so I apologize if I am missing something here, but as far as I can tell I am only passing in two parameters when I call the function: `self.near(az, -2.5003175907168385)`

Can anyone tell me why it thinks I'm passing in 3 parameters?

Comment: `def near(self, val1, val2):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to pass `self` in `near` function

`def near(self, val1, val2):`

[Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)

[What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: Oh - this is probably a stupid question, but why do I have to pass in `self` to my near function if I'm not referencing it there?

Comment: @AbeMiessler [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: There are three kinds of method of a python class-object. @AbeMiessler https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls

Answer (score 2):

It has been mentioned before but my answer would be "your method near should be static". 
Rather than passing self, I would make the method static using the @staticmethod decorator. This is given the fact that passing self has no benefits. Even more, if you pass self as an argument, a quality checker like Sonar Python Lint combination will flag it as "it should be static". This is something I often forget about it ([Module function vs staticmethod vs classmethod vs no decorators: Which idiom is more pythonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788195/module-function-vs-staticmethod-vs-classmethod-vs-no-decorators-which-idiom-is)).

Also, I would recommend passing margin as a variable as well rather than making it a global variable which I imagine it is at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The first variable in any class method is a reference to the class instance. Your method is expecting two variables: `val1` and `val2`, but when you call `self.near(val1, val2)` it is the equivalent of calling a function with `self`, `val1`, and `val2` as the arguments.

From [Python Docs on Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), second paragraph:

> the method function is declared with an explicit first argument
>   representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call