# Should this method be a classmethod and why can't it access vars?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, instance-variables, class-method

I come from java background, so I am slightly confused here.

Consider the code snippet below:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.obj_var = "I am obj var"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print cls.obj_var   # this line is in question here
        cls.cls_obj = "I m class object"
        return cls.cls_obj
```

This throws an error :

```
In [30]: a = A()

In [31]: a.obj_var
Out[31]: 'I am obj var'

In [32]: a.class_method()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3dcd9d512548> in <module>()
----> 1 a.class_method()

<ipython-input-29-9c0d341ad75f> in class_method(cls)
      8     @classmethod
      9     def class_method(cls):
---> 10         print cls.obj_var
     11         cls.cls_obj = "I m class object"
     12         return cls.cls_obj

AttributeError: class A has no attribute 'obj_var'
```

iIf I comment out `@classmethod`, this will work fine.

**My understanding** (*which is incorrect m sure*) :

When I do `a = A()`, then all the variables(`obj_var`) created in `__init__` can be accessed via this `a` when passed to any other `classmethod` of same class.Apparently this is not the case.

**Question(s)**

- why am i not able to access `__init__` `var`s  in `class_method` when decorater `@classmethod` is mentioned in the method but on removing the decorater, it works fine?
- how python internally process this particular class upon compilation?
- is there any way i can use `@classmethod` and the `__init__` vars in same method?

Comment: Why are you using `classmethod` if you want an instance method?

Comment: What you are calling "`__init__` vars" are instance attributes.  The reason a classmethod is called a classmethod is that it only has access to the class, not the instance.  Why are you using `classmethod` at all?

Comment: @BrenBarn : i am taking `__init__` as a constructor, wherein, once set, values can be used anywhere in the class methods...

Comment: @NoobEditor: *Why are you using* `classmethod`?  What do you think the purpose of `classmethod` is?  It sounds like you should read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) to understand how to use classes in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 : might sound super dumb...but what the difference between `classmethod` and `instance` method?
Accessing method via `object` is instance and doing `A(). class_method()` is class s method?

Comment: @BrenBarn : i did go through the documentation mate, thats always Step 1, what i am trying to do is come out of _java_ _shell_, in java `a=A()` `a.method()` `A().method()` is more or less same, but apparently not in python...this is what had me confused....makes sense?

Comment: @NoobEditor: Those are more or less the same, but again, you have not in any way explained why you are using `classmethod`.  You seem to be thinking that a classmethod is just any method you define in a class, but that is not the case.  You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788195/module-function-vs-staticmethod-vs-classmethod-vs-no-decorators-which-idiom-is).  If you want access to instance variables, don't use `classmethod`.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: Python classmethod is akin to Java static method

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *No they are not*.  Java static methods do not participate in polymorphism.  They cannot override or be overridden by other methods, static or otherwise, and cannot be polymorphically called at runtime without a whole lot of reflection.  Python has none of these restrictions.

Comment: @Kevin I said "akin to", not "the same as". Remember that asker is a novice who thinks that classmethod is an instance method. In terms of a simple and helpful analogy, my comment was reasonable.  A novice has no chance of making any sense of what you just said. Whilst I know all of what you said, do you think the asker can understand that yet? Think about the learning process. Your answer is pitched at totally the wrong level for the asker.

Comment: **Because you can't just access instance variables as if they were class variables; otherwise if you had 2+ instances, how would the class know which instance you meant to reference?!** b) You can't do this in Java classmethod either. c) Code smell: so if you can't implement a method as classmethod, then it's an instance method, not a classmethod...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's talk about how Python's methods actually work.

You may have noticed that Python methods are declared just like free-standing functions, but inside a class.  That's because Python methods *really are* free-standing functions that happen to be inside a class.  The `self`/`cls` argument is not special.  It's just the first argument of the function.

Before we go any further, I'd like to point out that you don't appear to be explicitly inheriting from `object`.  If you are working in Python 2.x, there is no `object` at the root of the graph unless you explicitly inherit from it.  **That is a bad thing**, and you should inherit directly or indirectly from `object` whenever possible in new code.  Inheriting from `object` in Python 3 is legal and harmless, but unnecessary.  The rest of this discussion assumes that you are either working in 3.x or have fixed this.

When you access a variable, function, method, or any other type of object with `foo.bar`, certain hooks known as the "descriptor protocol" get invoked.  You don't have to know the details of this to understand how functions work.  All you have to know is this:

1. First, if there's an instance variable `bar` directly attached to `foo` (and `foo` is not a class), we just return it directly.(*)
2. If `foo` is a class and `bar` is a `@classmethod` function(**) declared either in `foo` or in one of its superclasses, then the first argument is set to `foo` before we return it.  Otherwise, it is returned unchanged.(***)  If we returned something, we *stop here*.
3. We search the "method resolution order" of `foo`.  This consists of `foo`'s class (known as `type(foo)`), that class's superclass, and so on until we get to `object`.  In cases of multiple inheritance, this gets a little more complicated, but again, you don't need to know that.
4. Take the `bar` variable from the first class which has one (call it `Baz`).
5. If `Baz.bar` is a regular, undecorated function, set its first argument to `foo` and return it.
6. Otherwise, if `Baz.bar` is a `@classmethod` function, set its first argument to `type(foo)` and return it.
7. Otherwise, if `Baz.bar` is a `@staticmethod` function, or not a function(**) at all, return it unchanged.

As you can see, if the method is declared `@classmethod`, **the first argument is always the class, and never the instance,** regardless of how the function is invoked.  That means you don't have access to the instance variables of `foo`, since you don't have access to `foo` itself.  Any variables set in `__init__()` are instance variables, so they are not visible here.

And here are all the things I lied about:

(*): Python actually does the rest of this work first and then comes back to this step.  But that only matters for things like `@property`, which can actually override local instance variables.  Regular methods cannot.

(**): This is a lie.  Python also does special processing on `@property` functions in this case, and on anything else that implements certain special methods.

(***): I am also ignoring unbound methods in Python 2.x because, aside from certain really weird cases (when you try to pass an object of the wrong type as the first argument by hand), they make no difference whatsoever.  They do not exist in Python 3.

Comment: late...i know!!

Comment: I'd preface this with the one-liner "because you can't just access instance variables as class variables; otherwise if you had 2+ instances, how would the clas know which instance you meant to reference?!". Anyway this answer is overkill, the caveat "in Python 2.x, classes scould inherit from `object`, you should move that to a footnote. And the long part about MRO is overkill. OP is simply confused that they can't access instance variables as if they were class variables.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to access an instance variable from a class method you need to create an instance of the class where the instance variable is present.
Hope below code should work.

```
class A():
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.obj_var = "I am obj var"

@classmethod
def class_method(cls):
    self = cls() # Here you are creating an instance of the class (in this case it is class A)
    print(self.obj_var) 
    cls.cls_obj = "I m class object"
    return cls.cls_obj

 print(A.class_method())
```

Comment: Good solution, but you can't use the __init__ variables like below the code.
`class A():
    def __init__(self, ff, **kwargs):
        self.ff = ff
        self.obj_var = "I am obj var"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        self = cls() # Here you are creating an instance of the class (in this case it is class A)
        print(self.obj_var) 
        print("FF", self.ff)
        cls.cls_obj = "I m class object"
        return cls.cls_obj

print(A.class_method())`

Comment: **Output:**
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in class_method
TypeError: A.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ff'
> `

Comment: I did something else, which might be stupid. It works:
```@classmethod
def class_method(cls,obj,var):
   self=obj
   return self.var+var

res = A(A,6)