# How to share function between static methods #python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods

There are two static methods in my class:

```py
class my_class():
    def main(self, input):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_1():
        #repeated_code
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_2():
        #repeated_code
        pass
```

As they share some `#repeated_code`, I want to reduce the repetition in them by writing a function `def repeat()`for the `#repeated_code`.

Since they are inside static methods, I couldn't call a class method via `self.repeat()`.

It doesn't seems reasonable to write the function outside the class, because the function `repeat` is only used inside the class.

How should I achieve the propose of **avoiding repeating myself**?

Comment: I doubt it's a great idea to write your class like that. Normally, static methods are placed in a class for convenience purposes. For example, google style guide for Python recommends not using them: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html. Why not simply create a module with these functions? You can have your `repeat()` function in the same module as well and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right way to go - static methods are meant to be small convenience functions, and if you have to share code, they aren't small.

But, if you want to, you can call a static method by referencing the class by name, like this:

```
class test():
    @staticmethod
    def repeat():
        # shared code
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_1():
        test.repeat()

    @staticmethod
    def static_2():
        test.repeat()
```

Comment: Actually, I have no idea weather I should use a static method. Maybe I should follow your advice to not use them.

Comment: Well, it's a guideline, and guidelines are flexible. It may make sense to keep the code within the object, but maybe it doesn't need to be a static method. I checked the python 3.8 modules and found, for example, that ```importlib``` uses a 25-line static method with 2 inner functions, so sometimes there's use for it.

Comment: according to this [relavant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788195/module-function-vs-staticmethod-vs-classmethod-vs-no-decorators-which-idiom-is), I think I shouldn't make them static methods!   -->They are `__visualizing_debug_fucntions`, which would never be used outside the class.